# iOS on Jenkins: Provisioning profile can't be found

Tags: ios, jenkins, provisioning-profile

I know there are a lot of questions similar to mine on this site, but none seem to be what I am looking for with a few environment changes.

I'm running an osx Dumb Slave set up using Java Web Start.  I'm not running as root, nor a specific user entitled 'jenkins,' but rather a normal user.  I've installed the xcode plug-in on Jenkins.  Everything seems to start up fine, and it's loading the files on the slave server, however, once I begin to build (post-clean), I run into this error:

```
Provisioning profile '<uuid>' can't be found
```

I've set the certificate to both login AND system and just login and just system.  I copied the .p12 certificates that I was currently using on another machine.  I'm at a loss.  If anyone can possibly help or even link me to maybe some stackoverflow question I have yet to try, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to search through my project.pbxproj to all the provisioning profiles.  It seemed there was an old number and a new number (used in different apps).  I had to realign the provisioning number to the new one.